# How can I move an object using NDOF?

Tags: objects, add-on, 3d-mouse

I have a 3DConnexion SpaceNavigator. It works very well for moving the viewport. Is there a way for it to place an object in the scene?

Is this something that can be accomplished via an addon? I am new to Blender, I'm delighted that the NDOF works out of the box, but I expect to be able to place objects using it. Would be much more intuitive than using a mouse.

So far I have setup a ViewOperator template and I can see that moving the 3D mouse yields a NDOF_MOTION event

```
def modal(self, context, event):
        v3d = context.space_data
        rv3d = v3d.region_3d

        if event.type == 'NDOF_MOTION':
            print(event)
```

blender console when moving the 3d mouse: `<bpy_struct, Event at 0x000001B72D13B5F8>`

I can see how I might write a script to move an object given the motion event. The problem is I can not find any way to get data from the event. I am expecting some translation/rotation vectors but those properties don't seem to exist on the Event object.

I believe the c implementation to move the viewport is here: ndof_orbit_zoom_invoke() in https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/space_view3d/view3d_edit.c

`const wmNDOFMotionData *ndof = event->customdata;`

There is no `customdata` on the event when it gets to my python script.

Which makes sense because there is no mention of any relevant data in `rna_def_event()` here: https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_wm.c

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We are very interested in using the 3D mouse to move models in the scene.

Comment: @Madcowswe No, unfortunately. This caused me to lose interest in Blender and I've since moved on.

Comment: Stack Exchange isn't the only source of information! You can always drop by on IRC ([FreeNode, channel #blender](https://webchat.freenode.net/)), join mailing lists, or chat at [Blender.Chat](https://blender.chat/).

Comment: @Madcowswe have you asked around on IRC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, presently, there is no ndof_motion field in the python [Event struct](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Event.html).

I checked in with Blender's Python API module owner @ideasman42 on the #blendercoders IRC channel, and he gave the thumbs up to expose this data with an added field. So I will try my hand at adding that. Assuming that all works out, it should then be possible to make your proposed addon.

Comment: What's the status of this? Did you get it to work? How can I access it in python?

Comment: @JamRisser Sorry I ran out of time for this project, so I don't think I will be able to do it any time soon. It didn't look very complicated to do this though, so I'd recommend doing it if you have the time.

Comment: Could you give me a jump start by sharing your work with me?

Comment: @JamRisser I never got to writing any code, but I remember that between the `rna_def_event()` in https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_wm.c;45c11c1a1bd07cca255abdb1923e69f0242c36fd$1695

and the python event struct, I think that's the main path to get the data out by adding to those. There may be more to it, but then I would ask  @ideasman42 on the #blendercoders IRC channel.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if anyone is still interested with that but I made an addon for blender (on windows system only) to move object with a NDOF 3d connection space mouse.
You can find my tutorial on Youtube : https://youtu.be/Zw79EofTLbs
And the addon itself on Gumroad : https://julienroy.gumroad.com/l/TelekiNDOF

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)