# 3d connexion space mouse: how to move objects?

Tags: hardware, 3d-mouse

I recently got a 3Dconnexion Spacemous and everything worked perfectly, at least in the training setup. Now I tested the device in blender and even though the control of the viewpoint works excellently I can not rotate/move objects, like the cube in the startup example. I read some posts, with older timestamps stating that this option is no available, but really? It worked in the training why does not it work in blender. There must be some solution to this problem since I can not be the only one who wants to use such a feature. Please help!

Comment: I'll mention the obvious - at the bottom of the 3D screen is an icon that has two arrows pointing outward from each other. 

"<--...-->"

It toggles the lock on rotate etc. That might have got itself activated.

Comment: Did the training demo show it actually working **in Blender**? If not you can't just expect it to work because it worked in some other software under a controlled environment.

Comment: @Edgel3D unfortunately the obvious is not the problem. I am able to rotate the cube with the normal mouse. Just with the space mouse i can not get it to rotate.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos the training demo was some other program, I just mentioned this because I do not think that blender does not support this function since the function works in other software.

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone is still interested with that but I made an addon for blender (on windows system only) to move object with a NDOF 3d connection space mouse. You can find my tutorial on Youtube : https://youtu.be/Zw79EofTLbs
And the addon itself on Gumroad : https://julienroy.gumroad.com/l/TelekiNDOF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving objects with the Spacemouse has not been implemented in Blender, but good news is somebody is working on it! See [How can I move an object using NDOF?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/70859/34408)